# Number of maximum array member in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Just studying PowerShell and here is a question:
I need a order number of biggest array member.
Like in array 1,2,5,3,4 the biggest is member 3.
Thanks!

Comment: And i thought the biggest number would be 5 and it's index is 2....

Comment: My bad, forget to count from 0, not from 1. Anyway, how to get this index?

Comment: Q&A means Questions and Answers. If you want an answer, make an effort formulating a question first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a single function or step by step, let's see first step by step version.

Given an integer array `$a` you first need to find maximum value:

```
$maximum = ($a | Measure -Max).Maximum
```

Please note that `Measure-Object` will return a `Double` so it'll later need to be casted to `Int32`. Now you need to search at which index the first occurrence of that value is:

```
$index = [Array]::IndexOf($a, [int]$maximum)
```

Note that you can replace `IndexOf` with `LastIndexOf` if you want index of last element with the maximum value (for example given an array `(1,3,3,2,3)` with `IndexOf` you'll get `1` and with `LastIndexOf` you'll get `4`, don't forget arrays are 0-based).

You can put all together in a single line (if you want so):

```
$index = [Array]::IndexOf($a, [int](($a | Measure -Max).Maximum))
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
$index = [Array]::IndexOf($a, [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max([int[]]$a)
```

Let's make a function for this (let me be prolix):

```
function IndexOfMaximum($a)
{
    $maximum = $null
    $indexOfMaximum = -1

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; ++$i)
    {
        if ($maximum -eq $null -or $a[$i] -gt $maximum)
        {
            $maximum = $a[$i]
            $indexOfMaximum = $i
        }
    }

    return $indexOfMaximum
}
```

To be used like:

```
IndexOfMaximum($a)
```

<sub>Note: questions should show an attempt to solve the problem, I posted this answer (as Community Wiki) because I think PowerShell examples are never enough...</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much!  Exactly what i`m looking for!